# Can I map a Mac OS Extended Journaled partition on a Windows PC

Tags: windows-7, mac-osx-server, mappeddrive

I have a shared directory on a Mac Server that I want to map to my Windows 7 PC.

It worked fine on the old mac server as the hard drive was formatted as NTFS, but on this new one (which we got yesterday) the hard drive is Mac OS Extended (Journalled) and it's not happening.

Does anyone have any experience in this area?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean when you're talking about mapping the drive and how its formatting affects it. Typically if it's actually mapped over the network, it doesn't matter (other than with permissions).

If you want to share a Mac-hosted directory to a Windows system, use Samba (which is used for filesharing anyway.) Samba abstracts the permissions and filesystem from the clients. That's also why when you share drives from Windows you have sharing permissions AND file ACL's (from NTFS).

What you'll lose in sharing from the Mac is the finer ACL control from NTFS, since you have to use UNIX permissions to control file-level access. Or play with SAMBA permissions mapped to the Windows user for access control. But it works fine.

Otherwise you'll have to post details on what you're doing and why it isn't working (procedure, error messages, etc.) As posted your description is extremely vague.

Comment: Samba sounds perfect for what we need, a link to a tutorial (explaining what I need to do on the Mac, I know how to map a drive on a Windows PC) would be awesome!

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!